# Scraping Yahoo Earning Calendar

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am new to programming in Python.  I am trying to get the Symbol, and Time.

I am able to get the time that works for me.  It comes out with just the first word, sometimes it is a time, rather than a 'after/before' market closes.

But when it comes to the symbol I don't want any foreign markets, so nothing with a .?? in the symbol.  Here is what I have so far.  Sorry if it is a little sloppy.  It is my first real program in python....

```
import requests
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site= "http://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/acrx"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'}

url = "http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/20150309.html"

content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

m = re.findall('center><small>\S+ ', content)
w = re.findall('\?s=\w+',content)

x=0
lp = (len(m))
xlp = lp -1


for x in range (xlp):
    print x, m[x+1][14:], w[x][3:]
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using regex, you can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML. You can use the [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) library to get the current date as well.

Here's an example code for scraping yahoo finance.

```
import requests
import bs4

def get_earning_data(date):
    html = requests.get("https://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/{}.html".format(date), headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"}).text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
    quotes = []
    for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
        if len(tr.contents) > 3:
            if len(tr.contents[1].contents) > 0:
                if tr.contents[1].contents[0].name == "a":
                    if tr.contents[1].contents[0]["href"].startswith("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="):
                        quotes.append({     "name"  : tr.contents[0].text
                                           ,"symbol": tr.contents[1].contents[0].text
                                           ,"url"   : tr.contents[1].contents[0]["href"]
                                           ,"eps"   : tr.contents[2].text if len(tr.contents) == 6 else u'N/A'
                                           ,"time"  : tr.contents[3].text if len(tr.contents) == 6 else tr.contents[2].text
                                       })
    return quotes

print(get_earning_data("20150309"))
```

Comment: Still works! You just wrote my afternoon's code for me. Cheers, mate!